Using cite commands in section names (is there a cite command that does not produce a hyperlink?)
I would like to include a citation inside a section name, i.e.
\section{The model of \cite{Book}}

which then prints "The model of Author 2024". When I do this, lualatex complains with
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing `\cite' on input line xx.

For now I use
\section{The model of \texorpdfstring{\cite{Book}}{Author 2024}}

where I have to type the correct citation manually into the second argument. Is there a way to print a citation that does not produce a hyperlink, without turning off hyperlinks completely? I.e. how do I create a command
\newcommand{\citeInSectionName}[1}{\texorpdfstring{\cite{#1}}{\citeNoHyperlink{#1}}}

that can be used in a section name? As far as I know, biblatex does not have citation commands that do not produce a hyperlink.
MWE:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref=true,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Book,
author="Author",
title="Title",
year=2024,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{The model of \cite{Book}}

\section{The model of \texorpdfstring{\cite{Book}}{Author 2024}}

\end{document}


the problem is not the link, but that \cite is not expandable and hyperref has no idea what to write into the bookmarks. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1198

@UlrikeFischer So I asked this question twice, once in 2022 in that bug report and now again on tex.stackexchange.com :D

The answer is still the same, unfortunately: biblatex's citation commands are (still) not expandable.
